# Time course heatmap

Tags: r, time, data-analysis

How do I make time course heatmap like the picture below.
I have attached the structure of my data as well. It's 15k genes as rows and time points as columns, where the reading was taken every 12.5 minutes. I tried using gg plot but how do I know what time course genes I gave in my dataset? and cluster them together? Very new to coding so I'd appreciate a rough code draft I can start with and how can i filter my genes
[data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzXUa.png)

[time course heatmap example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPO01.png)

Comment: Hi Blogger Girl, welcome to SO! You may want to [read what makes a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help the community best answer your question. Two points in particular that will help: 1) post some minimal data in R format (you can upload it and use the `dput()` command) rather than an image of the data and 2) tell us what you want the final plot to look like based on your data (what would be the equivalent rows, columns, etc.).